# How to show correct nested child tab when page is reloaded or refreshed in Vue

Tags: vue.js, tabs

I am working on implementing nested tab view using custom tab component in Vue. When I refresh or reload the page for nested child tab, no active tab is shown. My question is how to show the active parent tab when page is refreshed/reloaded for the correct active child tab. Here I am providing the code to understand better.

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-leaf-zxlt7?file=/src/components/TabView.vue

To clarify more, Suppose, I am browsing here to Operation 2 Under the Operation Tab

[image: Suppose, I am browsing here to Operation 2 Under the Operation Tab]

Now, when I refresh the page, I got this-

[image: After refreshing]

I need to click the parent tab (Operation Tab) to see the active Child Tab (Operation 2)

Please, help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, it seems that you want the app to go to a specific route after a refresh. Perhaps you could implement vue-router, and save the most recent route in localstorage, then re-route the user to said most recent route when the app is refreshed.

You would need: implement vue-router so that the open tabs are saved into the route, use hooks or mixin to save most recent route to localstorage, use created() hooks in App.Vue to load the most recent route (if any) and use programmatic navigation to push user to the loaded most recent route.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited my question. Can you please look into it again.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly, your goal here is to keep the selected tabs open after reloading/refreshing the page. In that case you need to store the state of that component by creating new items in localStorage manually by calling `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` and then grabbing that values back in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook of your component with `localStorage.getItem('key', 'value')`. Alternatively you can use use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) with [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) plugin that will handle saving and loading the state of your app for you.

Comment: Actually, I am keeping that state but the problem is happening for nested child tab. Whenever I refresh while I am in the nested child tab, the parent tab is not activated, thus the nested child tab is also not shown. I need to manually click on the parent tab to see the nested child tab then.